# Using ffprobe to get count of audio streams in mp4 file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, ffprobe, mpeg4

I am looking for a way to get a count of the number of audio streams in mp4 files.  Among some big long threads (mostly pre-2019 dated) on using ffprobe for this I found the following command:

`ffprobe -i your_video.mp4 -show_entries stream=channels -select_streams a -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -v 0`

and that is repeated in other different places as an accepted answer. However, for me the command always returns the **total** stream count, not just the audio stream count that I want.

I am using the Windows build of ffprobe and ffmpeg (which I also tried to use).

**ffprobe version git-2020-04-12-f1894c2 Copyright (c) 2007-2020...**

I also found other variants of the command (again, all quite old) in other places, but of those, the ones which don't generate errors also return just the total stream count.

I have verified using ffmpeg and VLC that my test file (yes, i tried others too) really only has one video and one audio stream - which seems to be verified by output from

`ffmpeg -i filename`

as below:

```
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200328
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 42.102 / 56. 42.102
  libavcodec     58. 78.102 / 58. 78.102
  libavformat    58. 42.100 / 58. 42.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 77.101 /  7. 77.101
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '00015239.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.78.100
  Duration: 00:06:43.97, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3625 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 3492 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Clearly I am either misunderstanding something, or doing something wrong, or something has changed to since the commands above were accepted.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Alan T

Comment: Try using a "stable release" of FFprobe. I tested the accepted command using FFprobe version 6.1.1 and 5.1.2 in Windows, and version n4.3.1 in Linux. All gives the correct count of audio streams. In case there are two audio streams the output is `1` under `1` (in two rows).

Answer (score 1):

I usually use either `mediainfo` or `ffmpeg -i ...  2>&1 | grep -e '^\s*Stream\s*#.*\sAudio:' | wc -l`

*EDIT*

Since `ffmpeg` outputs to stderr by default, I forgot to put the redirection in - now fixed

Comment: It's not working for me, unless I append `2>&1` at the end of `ffmpeg` command. I wonder if `ffmpeg` does print to `stdout` by default.

Comment: Thanks for the good catch, edited the answer

Comment: Thanks for the responses here guys. 
As I am doing this project on Windows I have put together a PowerShell equivalent including the tips above.

```$lineCount = ffmpeg -i 00010875.mp4 2>&1 | select-string -pattern "Stream"  | select-string -pattern "audio" | measure-object -line```

``write-host $lineCount``

  now shows "1" as it should

Many thanks. It would be nice to use the ffprobe method - but this is plenty good for now.

Comment: Just so you know, PowerShell has 6 streams ([the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.4)), among which are _success_, _error_ and _warning_. You already seem to be OK, since it's been working for you. However, if you run into problems, you might need to redirect either all streams `*>&1` or inlcude warnings `3>&1 2>&1`.